# Какие существуют архитектуры взаимодействия с базой данных?

Tags: sql, .net, windows, архитектура, клиент-сервер

В своем приложении я выбрал такую архитектуру:
WinForms-клиент->WCF-Служба->ORM->БД<-WinService(На нем хостится WCF, а сам сервис в фоне решает некоторые задачи синхронизации БД.)

Клиент шлет запрос WCF службе, а WCF служба через ORM взаимодействует с БД и обрабатывает запросы клиента.
В свою очередь в фоне крутится Win служба на которой хостится WCF, а сама служба фоне выполняет манипуляции с данными с БД.

Как можно классифицировать данную архитектуру?

Какие существуют альтернативные архитектуры, их + и -?

Comment: Архитектуру выбирают применительно к задаче. Без описания задачи непонятно, удачен ли ваш выбор. У меня тут вопрос -- почему WinForms? сейчас для нового приложения обычно лучше делать фронт-енд в браузере.

Answer (score 1):

Такой подход обычно называют "трехзвенная архитектура".

Обычно ее рассматривают в сравнении с файл-серверной и клиент-серверной архитектурами.

- В файл-серверной архитектуре клиентское приложение работает непосредственно с файлами на сетевом ресурсе.
- В клиент-серверной архитектуре клиент взаимодействует с СУБД (серверу баз данных).

Comment: Т.е по сути существует 3 архитектуры взаимодействия с БД?

Comment: Можете еще про + и - написать?